# CLion and CMake Doesn't Complain but Failed to build OpenCV

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, linker-errors, clion

#### Summary

In Windows, CLion doesn't complain anything after cmake and before makefile.

- All code seems to link correctly without error. I am able to see the reference, documents, linter and jump into `cv::Mat` or `opencv.hpp` header file with `ctrl` `RMB`.
- CMake seems to correctly generate make files without error.

But the compile error occurs: `undefined reference to` OpenCV methods.

#### my setup

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(test)

# Set compile version
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(test ./test.cpp )
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

The output seems correct

```sh
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" D:\repo\CS5330\test
-- OpenCV library status:
--     version: 4.5.5
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_world
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_world
--     include path: /path/to/scoop/apps/opencv/current/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/test/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

And this generates `CMakeCache.txt`, which includes,

```
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH= /path/to/scoop/apps/opencv/current/x64/vc15/lib

//Details about finding OpenCV
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_OpenCV:INTERNAL=[/path/to/scoop/apps/opencv/current][v4.5.5()]
```

As you see, system-wide environment variable `OpenCV_DIR` has been already set and read correctly by CLion.

Here is a simple test code, but failed to run

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main() {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("./test.jpg", -1);
    cv::imshow("Mon image", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I also installed `msys2` from `winget`, and from `msys2` installed `clang`, `make`, `MinGW-w64 GDB`,`cmake`. Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/HO-COOH/CPPDevOnWindows/blob/master/README.md#install-clang).
And tested through that toolchain instead of CLion bundled toolchain, it returns the same result.

`OpenCV` binary is from `scoop`.

For some reason, it has the same problem as one from homebrew. In `opencv.hpp`, includes headers are incorrect due to file hierarchy that opencv.hpp is inside opencv2 folder.
I changed all `#include "opencv2/header.hpp"` to `#include "header.hpp"`, but it doesn't help, and vice versa.

Can't figure out the reason for hours.. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you're using mingw as compiler, you cannot use the libs from `x64/vc15/lib` , those are for VS *only*. you have to build opencv libs from scratch

Comment: or, if you are lazy, you can try: https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build